# MongoDB - How to write a query to find documents where ALL elements match a certain criteria containing multiple operators?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a collection in which every document has a "ratings" array, containing numbers varying from 0 to 10.

How do I write a query that searches for documents so that ALL elements inside the "ratings" array are, for example, $gt than 8 and $lt than 10?

Comment: Negate the condition and the operator, looking for all documents where there are no ratings less than 8 or greater than 10. $not with $elemMatch might do it.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!